All those years
Life isn't merely a collection of legendary moments, but those are the ones we cherish: the great milestones of humanity, the sparks of creativity, curiosity, exploration, and endurance. Even when no one else was there to witness these events, they shared one common trait: the timing was perfect. In other words, it was the right moment for them to happen.
To solve the puzzle, you'll need patience, curiosity, creativity, and perhaps a touch of luck. Who knows what might come your way.. This journey will guide you through significant historical moments, culminating in a reference to an object that holds a special place in my heart. Good luck, and enjoy the adventure!


Why did puzzle get a downvote? I think it’s perfectly well thought through…

The two rows of rebuses in this puzzle have two different themes:

 The top row resolves to various brands of wristwatch:

 ROLL + X = ROLEX
 STURM (German for 'storm') + MAN + SKI = STURMANSKIE (no Wiki page)
 HAM + MILL + TON = HAMILTON
 OHM + MEGA = OMEGA

 The second row resolves to a word relating to a historic event or figure:

 EVER (not 'never') + (-w)EST = EVEREST
 VOLVO - VOL(-tron) + STOCK + 1 = VOSTOK 1
 SUDOKU - SUDO + BRICK = KUBRICK
 APOLLO + EL + EVEN (not 'odd') = APOLLO 11

 These events (or figures) are, respectively: The first conquest of Mount Everest by Edmund Hillary and Tenzing Norgay, the first human spaceflight in history (Yuri Gagarin, aboard Vostok 1), the movie director Stanley Kubrick, and the first moon landing (achieved in the rocket Apollo 11, crewed by Neil Armstrong, Buzz Aldrin and Michael Collins).

What do the 4 rows of partially shown 4-digit numbers represent?

 These are the years (hence this puzzle's title) associated with the events and figures just uncovered:

1953 - first conquest of Everest;
 1961 - first human spaceflight;
2001: A Space Odyssey - an iconic Kubrick movie;
 1969 - the first moon landing.

How do these connect to the top row?

 In each column, there are wristwatches of this brand very famously involved in the event in question!

 - Edmund Hillary wore a Rolex on his Everest ascent;
 - Yuri Gagarin wore a Sturmanskie during the Vostok 1 mission;
 - A Hamilton watch featured in 2001: A Space Odyssey;
 - The Omega Speedmaster was worn by Neil Armstrong during the moon landing mission.

So the puzzle is tying together, what with the references to 'timing' in the flavourtext too. Finally then, let's work out what object 'holds a special place in [the OP's] heart'...

 The numbers we have had to enter into the years, from left to right, are 1360099. With the wristwatch theme, this leads me to surmise that the object in question might be an Omega Geneve 136.0099, a specific wristwatch that may hold some particular value to the question asker here...


spot on :) that was very fast..

@zlobi.wan.kenobi I happened to be checking on the homepage when you posted! Solving the 3rd column in its entirety helped me spot the connection. Really nice puzzle, by the way - a theme I've never seen used before; all tied together very nicely!

thank you. To share the credit, my inspiration comes from TMT (themastertheorem). I enjoy this unique mix of visuals and plot telling a story.

Nice solve and write up, but... how do you get from 10^3 to mega?

@fljx By mistake, it seems, since (as I'm sure underlies your comment) 10^3 is actually KILO in metric prefixes, and MEGA would be 10^6. Oops.

Oh, apologies for that.. 10ˆ6 indeed.. I corrected that five years ago (as the puzzle was created), but now managed to upload the erroneous draft. Trying to correct it now, thanks for the remark!

Edited the post now with the "final" final version. And btw, I made the omega representation indeed somewhat complicated, because it was initially meant as an entertainment for a bunch of watch aficionados and just using the omega sign seemed too obvious.

@zlobi.wan.kenobi Ok, will update my answer to match :)
